# Can Vue.js be used to manipulate dynamic content?

Tags: jquery, iframe, vue.js

I have a page consisting of a panel of UI controls designed to manipulate dynamic content that gets inserted into an iFrame on the same page.

For some time I have had my mind set on using Vue.js to link the controls to their targets in the iFrame, but now I am not sure it is even suitable for that. As I see it, the dynamic content is the problem and I am actually a bit surprised and somewhat disappointed that I have hit a roadblock so soon with Vue.

But there is always the possibility that I have missed something in my assessment or I could get what I need with a simple plugin or maybe just a minor change in perspective? So, before I bin it (Vue.js) I would like to ask you if I see this the wrong way.

I have seen quite a few tutorials that characterize Vue.js as an alternative (or an upgrade, really) to jQuery, but I don’t see that to be the case here. The great thing about jQuery is that you can target ANYTHING and you can do it very quickly with very little preparation.

That does not seem to be the case with Vue.js. Correct me if I am wrong but it seems that every element you target must be prepared first - typically via combinations of Vue.js directives, text interpolation, event handling etc. This can be grouped under declarative rendering.

Another observation is that in all the use cases I have seen with Vue.js so far, UI controls and targets are both kept within (as child elements) the element that a Vue.js instance targets. Here is an example from the documentation to illustrate that:

```
<div id="app-5">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
</div>

var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    reverseMessage: function () {
      this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

In my use case, if I had to include both controls and targets in one Vue instance, I would have to target a node quite high in the DOM.

Finally, let me finish up with a simple example from my use case: Let's say I have a slider in my panel of controls (just a normal input with type of range) and I want it to control the padding of a paragraph inside my iFrame knowing that the paragraph is dynamic and cannot be prepared for Vue binding on beforehand: Could I still use Vue for it or should I stick with jQuery?
Thank you.

Comment: Vue can do this, but i think you'll have to use the low level render function instead of the convenient templates. Here's an example of data binding to an iframe. https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/ohznser9/

Comment: @Erin Guan. The constraint in my question is that the iFrame content is dynamic and CANNOT be prepared for Vue binding on beforehand. In your example it is, so as I see it, it does not cut it. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: "the paragraph is dynamic"  What is making the paragraph "dynamic"?  Typically this would be Vue itself.   If you've got a situation where the DOM is being manipulated unexpectedly from some other source, then, yeah, Vue isn't going to be well suited to that use case (neither is any similar framework.)  It sounds from your description that you've basically misunderstood the purpose of these frameworks; they're not for minor tweaks to individual DOM elements, they're for building and controlling the entire DOM.

Comment: I agree with you. I have misunderstood. But I don’t think I am to blame: According to vuejs.org, it should be “easy to pick up and integrate with other libraries or existing projects.” To me, that sounds like something you can add on top of existing functionality. Only, there is a huge difference between that and “building and controlling the entire DOM” as you write, which would require early integration in most projects. In addition, you can find many examples where Vue is seen as a more sophisticated alternative to jQuery. Anyway, I think I can conclude: Vue goes in the bin.

Comment: Well, I can't speak to where you formed the impression that Vue is just a bigger/better jQuery, but yeah: it's not that.  They're different tools for different purposes.  You're kinda dismissing a screwdriver for being insufficiently similar to a hammer.  I'd encourage you to try Vue for a use case that it's actually suited to, rather than "binning" it because it doesn't work for a use case that it's really *not* suited to...

Comment: Can’t see why I shouldn’t dismiss it since – to stay in your analogy – my problem is a "nail". I have no general problem with Vue.

Comment: Perhaps [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) could be used via Vue code to communicate with the iframe... How is the jQuery code currently achieving the "_manipulate dynamic content that gets inserted into an iFrame on the same page_"? Could you create an example with [plunker](https://plnkr.co) (in case the iframe could have one of multiple templates)?